# Creating dataset index from unique combinations of columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset stored as a numeric matrix. The first 4 columns uniquely identify a "case". Each case is a procedure performed in a patient in a hospital on a certain date. So, the first column is hospital id, 2nd column is patient id, 3rd column is date, and 4th column is procedure type. What is the easiest way to assign a single column unique id based on unique combinations of the 4 columns. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need to combine the other data for the unique id? Why would a simple integer id (e.g. the row) not work?

Comment: For each "case" we have 2 raters, so unique cases are different from unique rows, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just concatenate them into one long number?

```
m = [1,4,2,3;
    5,6,1,4;
    8,3,2,6];

for i=1:3
    %http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/132022
    uid(i)  = str2num(sprintf('%-1d',m(i,:)));
end

m = [uid,m];
```

this gives output:

```
m =

        1423           1           4           2           3
        5614           5           6           1           4
        8326           8           3           2           6
```